# Is it possible to use Angular RouterModule without importing it with .forRoot()?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

What I'm trying to achieve is to make my `AppRoutingModule` unaware of actual application routes list.

`forRoot` call requires routes list, and samples use it in this way:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

It forces `AppRoutingModule` to be aware of `myRoutes`. But it should be the opposite, and what I need is to initialize my routing from application module like `appRoutingModule.AddRoutes(myRoutes)`.

Is it possible to initialize `RouterModule` not at the moment of import, but later by method call? When I tried to call `forRoot` in method and not in `imports` statement, it failed with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to initialize RouterModule not at the moment of import,
>   but later by method call?

No, that's not possible. When Angular compiles modules it merges all the providers defined in them. Read more in [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f). The `forRoot` method of `RouterModule` actually defines many application-wide providers like `Location`, `UrlSerializer`, `RouterPreloader` etc. These providers need to be compiled before the module starts.

> to make my AppRoutingModule unaware of actual application routes list.

So why not create an intermediary module then that will link `RouterModule` and `AppRoutingModule` together.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I put `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)]` into main application module instead of my `AppRoutingModule` and it worked right away.

Comment: @IvanZverev, glad I could help. Good luck